# How to connect two routers to the same network via an F-connector?

Tags: cisco, router, wireless, bridging

To clarify the situation, my ISP gave me a Cisco EPC3928S router which has F-connector input like shown in the picture below.

[image: cisco]

[image: cisco]

On the second floor they set an additional coax cable for the television. I did already try to connect the router to this cable and it works. So, my question is: Can I connect a second router using that cable on the second floor while the default one is connected( I mean at the same time) to extend my wifi range? and no I can’t just connect them with an ethernet cable, because they are too far.

Comment: Unfortuantely, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

coax line is your wide area where your isp connection is set. So connecting coax with a second modem is like buying a second circuit from isp. What you need is an Access point to connect your modem via ethernet cable (yellow ones) and configure it with the same SSID and password. Place it on the other floor.